# Falha com PostAsJsonAsync - WebApi - C#

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Fiz uma `WebAPI` que pelo `Postman` eu consigo fazer um `CRUD` completo, porem criei um `Windows Forms C# pelo Visual Studio` e estou com alguns problemas.

Consigo dar um `get` e todos meus dados são buscados perfeitamente, só que aoem ao dar um `post`, aparentemente da um retorno `Ok 200 do methodo Post`, mas nada é criado no meu banco.

Esse é meu `controle`:

```csharp
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]PROJETO projeto)
{
     var model = new ProjetoCriarEditarViewModel();
     model.CriarProjeto = _projetoBO.CriarProjeto(projeto);

     return Ok(model.CriarProjeto);
}
```

Esse aqui é o meu método no C#.

```csharp
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:19832/");


        PROJETO project = new PROJETO();
        project.NOME = textBox1.Text;
        project.DATA_INICIO = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        project.DATA_PREVISTA = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        project.TECNOLOGIA = textBox2.Text;
        project.VALOR = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
        project.STATUS_PROJETO = textBox4.Text;
        project.ID_CLIENTE = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);


        var resposta = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/projetos/", project);
        bool retorno = await resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
    }
}
```

Comment: só pra garantir, seu `_projetoBO.CriarProjeto` está dando _commit_ ao fim processo?

Comment: Sim. Eu consigo dar um post pelo postman usando a api e ele cria perfeitamente no banco de dados da minha aplicação. E tambem consigo usar "_projetoBO.CriarProjeto" em toda app.

Comment: Colocou o atributo [HttpPost] em cima do seu Controller?

Comment: Não coloquei pois ele entende que é um Post pelo nome do método. Então nesse caso nao faz diferença.

Comment: @joaop.mr Mas tu testou com o atributo? Fazer o post com o atributo através do código e não do postman?

Comment: Testei por desencargo rs e nada.

Comment: se já debugou? outra coisa o que dentro desse código: CriarProjeto?

Comment: Ja debuguei. Ele retorna o metodo post OK 200. Como se tivesse gravado. Porem não grava.

Comment: CriarProjeto é meu metodo nas regras de negocio que leva pro repositório. Outra coisa, uso o Entity Framework.

Comment: Você tem que debugar o código do repositório!

Comment: Mas eu consigo enviar pelo Postman. E tambem consigo gravar na aplicação. De qualquer forma o farei.

Answer (score 1):

Vou colocar um exemplo de método que eu utilizo em meus projetos e até hoje nunca me deu dor de cabeça. Está um pouco diferente do seu, creio que talvez estes detalhes façam diferença.

```
private async Task<bool> PostoToAPIAsync(PROJETO projeto)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:19832/api/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Converte seu objeto para formato Json
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(projeto);

    // Espera o resultado
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("projetos", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    // Verifica se o retorno é 200
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Perceba que alterei o endereço da sua API e coloquei uma `/` no final:

```
http://localhost:19832/api/
```

E removi a `/` do método da sua API:

```
projetos
```

Além disso, perceba que o método que criei é `async`, então você deve chamá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
PROJETO project = new PROJETO();
project.NOME = textBox1.Text;
project.DATA_INICIO = dateTimePicker1.Value;
project.DATA_PREVISTA = dateTimePicker2.Value;
project.TECNOLOGIA = textBox2.Text;
project.VALOR = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
project.STATUS_PROJETO = textBox4.Text;
project.ID_CLIENTE = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);

if(await PostoToAPIAsync(project))
{
   // Criado com sucesso
}
else
{
   // Erro ao criar
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Fiz exatamente isso amigo. Continuo com o mesmo problema. Ele retorna sucesso mas não grava nada no banco.